# Search Service Application

Tags: 2010, search, crawl

I am learning about the SharePoint Search Service Application and something is not clear to me.

I just learned that I can add a new index partition and use it as a mirror or a new one so that the index will be divided in those two.

I created a mirror and it copied all the index to new partition, which I was hoping to happen.

So now I have two index partitions on a different server than the one running the crawler component, but I still have a folder with the same name in the crawler server(SharePoint Index), but this one is much smaller, less than 100mb. The SharePoint Index folders in the server where the index partition is setted are huge as we have a huge content database.

What is the importance of the folder in the Crawler Server? Can I erase it? If I change the crawler to a different server and copy this folder will something break?(assuming everything is pointing to the right place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use PowerShell to "move" components. Don't delete any folders, SharePoint will manage the data file structure for you. You never need to manually copy any files or folders related to search, the components will manage themselves.

Comment: Picture this scenario: 1 crawler server and 2 index partitions(on different servers). In the crawler server we have two physical disks, each divided in two partitions. The crawler path is g:/ which is one partition of disk 1. The support team is going to rearrange the disks in a way that g:/ will be reallocated to the second disk in the crawler server, but still with the same name g:/. Would that affect sharepoint?

Comment: I don't quite get your scenario, but the safe answer is yes. If it were me, before I did any system level work on drives, I would move the index to a "safe location" then change, configure, format the drives (64k blocks for index drives) then move the index to the prepared location.